# PHP Soap doesn't create the correct xml document

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am trying to use this WSDL-service: https://wsaimport.uni-login.dk/wsaimport-v5/ws?WSDL

It needs an XML-document with information about users to import. When importing a person, two attributes are mandatory (according to https://wsaimport.uni-login.dk/wsaimport-v5/ws?xsd=1): (e.g. `<xs:attribute name="protected" type="xs:boolean" use="required">`).

I produce an object with the required information (and more, of course)  (the user and personal id are fake):

> object(XMLinst)#5 (1) {
>     ["UNILoginImport"]=>   object(UNILoginImport)#6 (5) {
>       ["sourceDateTime"]=>
>       string(19) "2018-10-20T00:15:54"
>       ["source"]=>
>       string(10) "SurveyInfo"
>       ["schoolYear"]=>
>       string(9) "2018-2019"
>       ["sourceVersion"]=>
>       string(3) "0.1"
>       ["Institution"]=>
>       object(Institution)#7 (4) {
>         ["InstitutionNumber"]=>
>         string(5) "10150"
>         ["InstitutionName"]=>
>         NULL
>         ["Group"]=>
>         object(Group)#8 (7) {
>           ["GroupId"]=>
>           string(2) "7b"
>           ["GroupName"]=>
>           string(3) "7.B"
>           ["GroupType"]=>
>           string(11) "Hovedgruppe"
>           ["GroupLevel"]=>
>           string(2) "DT"
>           ["Line"]=>
>           string(1) "B"
>           ["FromDate"]=>
>           string(10) "2018-08-01"
>           ["ToDate"]=>
>           string(10) "2019-06-30"
>         }
>         ["InstitutionPerson"]=>
>         array(1) {
>           [0]=>
>           object(InstitutionPerson)#9 (5) {
>             ["LocalPersonId"]=>
>             string(11) "310900-8345"
>             ["Person"]=>
>             object(Person)#10 (16) {
>               ["protected"]=>
>               bool(false)
>               ["verificationLevel"]=>
>               string(1) "0"
>               ["FirstName"]=>
>               string(9) "Tester A."
>               ["FamilyName"]=>
>               string(9) "Testersen"
>               ["CivilRegistrationNumber"]=>
>               string(11) "310900-8345"
>               ["EmailAddress"]=>
>               NULL
>               ["BirthDate"]=>
>               string(10) "2000-09-31"
>               ["Gender"]=>
>               string(1) "M"
>               ["PhotoId"]=>
>               NULL
>               ["AliasFirstName"]=>
>               NULL
>               ["AliasFamilyName"]=>
>               NULL
>               ["Address"]=>
>               NULL
>               ["HomePhoneNumber"]=>
>               NULL
>               ["WorkPhoneNumber"]=>
>               NULL
>               ["MobilePhoneNumber"]=>
>               NULL
>               ["GroupId"]=>
>               string(2) "7b"
>             }
>             ["Student"]=>
>             object(Student)#11 (6) {
>               ["Role"]=>
>               string(4) "Elev"
>               ["StudentNumber"]=>
>               NULL
>               ["Level"]=>
>               string(2) "DT"
>               ["Location"]=>
>               string(8) "B-rummet"
>               ["MainGroupId"]=>
>               string(2) "7b"
>               ["GroupId"]=>
>               NULL
>             }
>             ["Employee"]=>
>             NULL
>             ["Extern"]=>
>             NULL
>           }
>         }
>       }   } }

I am calling the client, and then the import function:

`$unilogin = new SoapClient($WSDL,array("soap_version"  => SOAP_1_2,'cafile' => "/etc/ssl/certs/surveyinfo.pem", 'cache_wsdl'=>"WSDL_CACHE_NONE", 'cache'=>"WSDL_CACHE_NONE", 'trace'=>true));`

`$unilogin->importerDeltaXml(array("wsBrugerid"=>$user,"wsPassword"=>$pass,"xml"=>$import));`

This returns an error:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'protected' must appear on element 'ns3:Person'.

The return from getLastResponse looks like this:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="https://uni-login.dk" xmlns:ns2="https://uni-login.dk/data" xmlns:ns3="https://wsaimport.uni-login.dk/import" xmlns:ns4="https://wsaimport.uni-login.dk/ws"><env:Body><ns4:importerDeltaXml><ns1:wsBrugerid/><ns1:wsPassword/><ns4:xml><ns3:UNILoginImport sourceVersion="0.1" sourceDateTime="2018-10-20T00:12:28" source="SurveyInfo" schoolYear="2018-2019"><ns3:Institution><ns2:InstitutionNumber>10150</ns2:InstitutionNumber><ns2:Group><ns2:GroupId>7b</ns2:GroupId><ns2:GroupName>7.B</ns2:GroupName><ns2:GroupType>Hovedgruppe</ns2:GroupType><ns2:GroupLevel>DT</ns2:GroupLevel><ns2:Line>B</ns2:Line><ns2:FromDate>2018-08-01</ns2:FromDate><ns2:ToDate>2019-06-30</ns2:ToDate></ns2:Group><ns3:InstitutionPerson><ns2:LocalPersonId>310400-8444</ns2:LocalPersonId><ns3:Person><ns2:FirstName>Tester A.</ns2:FirstName><ns2:FamilyName>Testersen</ns2:FamilyName><ns2:CivilRegistrationNumber>310400-8444</ns2:CivilRegistrationNumber><ns2:BirthDate>2000-04-31</ns2:BirthDate><ns2:Gender>K</ns2:Gender></ns3:Person><ns3:Student><ns2:Role>Elev</ns2:Role><ns2:Level>DT</ns2:Level><ns2:Location>B-rummet</ns2:Location><ns2:MainGroupId>7b</ns2:MainGroupId></ns3:Student></ns3:InstitutionPerson></ns3:Institution></ns3:UNILoginImport></ns4:xml></ns4:importerDeltaXml></env:Body></env:Envelope>`

As you can see, the `protected` and `verificationLevel` are not part of the XML, even though they were present in the object presented to SOAP. As you can also see, the SOAP-client function in PHP is actually capable of producing attributes as requested by the WSDL-document, because it is done in the `<ns3:UNILoginImport>` tag.

Have I come accross a bug in PHP's SoapClient? Or is something wrong in the WSDL-documents? (it is produced by a Danish Government agency, and a number of companies are using it already).

Any advice on how to get around this problem? I have tried to use the XML-document I get from __getLastRequest, inserting the requested attributes, but when sending this XML-document, after putting it through new SoapVar, I get "Failed to copy a message"...
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround by extending the SOAP-client the following way:

```
class HackSoapClient extends SoapClient {

        function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = NULL) {

            $request=str_replace('<ns3:Person>','<ns3:Person protected="false" verificationLevel="0">',$request);
            // parent call
            return parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version,$one_way);
        }
    }
```